# Xml serialization Exception : The type UserQuery+SpecificContentItem was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I have a problem on serializing a class to XML. I have created a sample code that runs an shows the error. The class I want to serialize named "ContentContainer", ContentContainer has a collection of items that its type is "ContentItemBase". because my requirements I implemented these classes as follow. but when the code reaches to the part if actual serialization call, serializer throws this exception :

> The type UserQuery+SpecificContentItem was not expected. Use the
>   XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not
>   known statically.

I have searched on this problem but my requirements I can't implement the XmlInclude method that mentioned in exception message. 
is there any solution (Design OR Implementation Tip) for this problem and similar problems?

CODE :

```
void Main()
{
    var item  = new SpecificContentItem{ Name = "Test", Value = "TestValue" , SpecificField="TestField"};
    var container = new ContentContainer();
    container.Items.Add(item);
    container.Name = "Test Container";
    XmlSerializer ser=  new XmlSerializer(typeof(ContentContainer));
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    ser.Serialize(writer, container);
    string result = writer.ToString();
}
public abstract class ContentItemBase
{
    public abstract string Name {get; set;}
    public abstract string Value {get; set;}
}

public class SpecificContentItem: ContentItemBase
{
    public string SpecificField {get; set;}
    public override string Name {get; set;}
    public override string Value {get; set;}
}
public class ContentContainer
{
    public ContentContainer()
    {
        Items = new ContentItemCollection();
    }
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public ContentItemCollection Items{get; set;}
}

public class ContentItemCollection : IEnumerable<ContentItemBase>
{
        public SpecificContentItem SpecificItem { get; set; }
        public IEnumerator<ContentItemBase> GetEnumerator()
        {
            if (SpecificItem != null)
                yield return SpecificItem;
        }
        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
        public void Add(Object obj)
        {
            if (obj is SpecificContentItem)
                SpecificItem = (SpecificContentItem)obj;
        }
}
```

Comment: Uh. Any particular reason you can't use XmlInclude?

Comment: But hey, kudos for using LINQPad to try out your code. Far too few people actually bother to make snippets that properly describe their problem in a tool such as that.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the XmlInclude on the "ContentContainer" class is there any method to use that on my "ContentItemCollection" class?

Comment: If you put `[XmlInclude(typeof(SpecificContentItem))]` on the `ContentItemCollection` class, it works wonders in my linqpad atleast. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating your serializer as:

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ContentContainer), 
                            new Type[] { typeof(SpecificContentItem) });
```

should do the trick.

You can also add a `Serialize` method to `ContentContainer` class

```
public string Serialize()
{
    var types = Items.Select(x => x.GetType()).Distinct().ToArray();
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ContentContainer),types);
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    ser.Serialize(writer, this);
    return writer.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Does this solution break the "Local Consequences" principle?
the serialization part of my project is in another dll.

Comment: @L.B. I would really advise you **not** to use this overload of the `XmlSerializer` constructor as it uses NO caching for the in-memory generated serializer assembly. Therefore this will cause performance issues and unseen memory usage issues as it creates a new assembly on **every time** you call that constructor.

Comment: What if the instanced serializer itself is cached, not relying on magic behind the scenes assembly caching?

Comment: @J.Steen That would be a fine solution as it will then only once create the assembly that you will reuse.

Answer (score 0):

Since the allowed use of `XmlInclude` seems to be ambiguous, I'm still going to suggest

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(SpecificContentItem))]
public class ContentItemCollection : IEnumerable<ContentItemBase>
{
```

as a possible solution. How that applies with your real world situation is a bit more difficult to tell, but I hope it's applicable and works!

Comment: this not worked in my real situation. i don't know why this worked in linqpad version of problem.. :|

Comment: Then I agree with the previous two answers to use the constructor overload of XmlSerializer that takes multiple type parameters - and caching the serializer manually if it's going to be reused.